# Error Conversion String to Date WebService

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, weblogic

Guys,

I´m writing an app which is a WebService but I´ve been facing a strange issue.
When I call the W.S I receive this error:

```
Exception Description: The object [2013-08-04T12:00:00:00], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[dateEvent-->dateEvent/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(br.com.gvt.armanagementapp.service.to.ReceivableInvoiceIn --> [DatabaseTable(ns0:receivableInvoiceIn)])], could not be converted to [class java.util.Calendar].
```

But my Objet ReceivableInvoiceIn there isn´t an attribute with java.util.Calendar there is an atributte java.util.Date

Has anyone faced this issue?

My environment is Weblogic12c with maven

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string into a `Date`

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I think is a bug on Weblogic12c1.1 when you perform a simple test with Webblogic ´s WebService Client , it puts a blank spaces into the tag like this:

```
<code>
<dateEvent>
    <!--date time format: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss--> 
    1999-12-24T22:00:00
</dateEvent>
</code>
```

The solution is split the blank spaces:

```
<code>
<dateEvent>1999-12-24T22:00:00</dateEvent>
</code>
```